# Iam getting an issue like "cannot find **-lopencv_contrib", while running but i installed the library & how i fix this issue?

Tags: compiling

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Iotdriver.d" -MT"Iotdriver.d" -o "Iotdriver.o" "../Iotdriver.cpp"
Finished building: ../Iotdriver.cpp

Building target: IOTpjt
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "IOTpjt"  ./Iotdriver.o   -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml  -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_objdetect
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find **-lopencv_contrib**
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -**lopencv_legacy**
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [IOTpjt] Error 1
makefile:44: recipe for target 'IOTpjt' failed
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068365/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lopencv-contrib

Answer (score 0):

According to search results on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=opencv_contrib) you need to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install libopencv-contrib-dev libopencv-legacy-dev
```